# HTML5 drag and drop events

Tags: html

HTML5 drag and drop events behave as follows:

1. 'dragging' removes the element, being dragged, from its location - I want it to remain even   after it's dragged.
2. drop event uses "appendchild" method which just 'appends' the dropped element. However I want it to be 'added' not 'appended'. Basically, if another element is dropped, then it should replace the already existing element rather than appending the second element.

Are these requirements possible?

Regards,

Abinash.

Comment: If you use `appendChild` then the element will be removed from where it was and appended where you add it, if you want more than one element you'll need to clone it.  Please post your code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: function drop(ev)
{
   ev.preventDefault();
   var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   alert(data);
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
Now, cloneNode(true) solves the first part. However, upon dropping an element, I want it to replace the already existing element in the <div> (if any).

Comment: @user1592320 why not use JQuery-UI to do this? Drag & Drop is built-in. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: Edit your question, don't cram code into comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <script>
        var dragSrcEl = null;

        function handleDragStart(e) {
          // Target (this) element is the source node.
          this.style.opacity = '0.4';

          dragSrcEl = this;

          e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
          e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

        }

        function handleDragOver(e) {
          if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
          }

          e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

          return false;
        }

        function handleDragEnter(e) {
          // this / e.target is the current hover target.
          this.classList.add('over');
        }

        function handleDragLeave(e) {
          this.classList.remove('over');  // this / e.target is previous target element.
        }
        function handleDrop(e) {
          // this/e.target is current target element.

          if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
            this.classList.remove('over');
          }

          // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
          if (dragSrcEl != this) {
            // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
            dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
          }

          return false;
        }



        function handleDragEnd(e) {
          // this/e.target is the source node.
          this.style.opacity = '1.0';
          [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
            col.classList.remove('over');
          });
        }
        function registerEvents()
        {
            var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
            [].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
              col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
              col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
              col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
              col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
              col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
              col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
            });
        }
        window.onload = registerEvents;
    </script>
    <style>
        /* Prevent the text contents of draggable elements from being selectable. */
        [draggable] {
          -moz-user-select: none;
          -khtml-user-select: none;
          -webkit-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
          /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */
          -khtml-user-drag: element;
          -webkit-user-drag: element;
        }
        .column {
          height: 150px;
          width: 150px;
          float: left;
          border: 2px solid #666666;
          background-color: #ccc;
          margin-right: 5px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
          -ms-border-radius: 10px;
          -moz-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;
          -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
          -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: move;
        }
        .column.over {
          border: 2px dashed #000;
        }

        .column header {
          color: #fff;
          text-shadow: #000 0 1px;
          box-shadow: 5px;
          padding: 5px;
          background: -moz-linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
          background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,
                                       color-stop(0, rgb(0,0,0)),
                                       color-stop(0.50, rgb(79,79,79)),
                                       color-stop(1, rgb(21,21,21)));
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
          background: -ms-linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
          border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
          -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
          -ms-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
          border-top-left-radius: 10px;
          -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
          -ms-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
          -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
          border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body >
    <div id="columns">
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>A</header></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>B</header></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>C</header></div>
    </div>
</body>
```